# Mvc HttpGetAttribute is accepting Http POST requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know if there are any particular circumstances when the `[HttpGet]` attribute gets ignored?

I have a controller that has an action with the `[HttpGet]` defined on it, which should mean that only GET requests are allowed and POST requests are rejected usually with a 404. Running locally under IIS this action seems to be able to accept Http POST requests however on the Test server this is not the case which is how it should be. It looks like we do need to be able to support POST request on the controller actions and we will be adding the support for this.

However this does raise the question as why my local copy of the site running under IIS seems to accept the requests. I would expect the request to rejected with a 404 http status. Also we have other sites running on the Test server that are behaving the same as my local server.

I am not sure if it has something to do with the fact that the requests are actually redirect requests. The 'main site / portal' is an old ASP.Net Web Forms application that then redirects to another 'routing' ASP.Net Mvc 3 web application that will re-route the request depending on business logic to 1 of 3 other 'channel' ASP.Net Mvc 3 web applications. All the channels essentially provide the same function but have slightly different business logic within them. Each channel has a landing controller that will redirect the user to the page where they should be going to. And it is the action on these ladning controllers that have the `[HttpGet]` attribute on.

The following is what occurs on 1 of the 3 channels on the test server:

1. User clicks a button
2. POST request to the 'Portal' site results in 302 to the 'Routing' site
3. POST request to the 'Routing' site results in 302 to the 'Channel' site
4. POST requets to the 'Channel' site results in 404.

The following is what ocurrs on the other 2 channels on the test server and on all 3 channels on my local server:

1. User clicks a button
2. POST request to the 'Portal' site results in 302 to the 'Routing' site
3. POST request to the 'Routing' site results in 302 to the 'Channel' site
4. POST requets to the 'Channel' site results in 302 to the destination page within the 'Channel' site.
5. POST request to the 'Channel' for destination page results in 200 and the page being servered.

UPDATE:
It turns out that I've been well and truly led up the garden path. The redirected requested are all being done via Http GET and not Http POST as is the correct behaviour for a 302 redirect. However IE developer tools incorrectly displays these as POST requests instead of GET requests. It turns out that the channel server had not been deployed to Test.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A http response with a 302 status for a http request with a POST method / verb will result in a new Http Request with a GET method / verb. This means that a redirect to an action on a controller with the `[HttpGet]` attribute will be successful.